# How do I get a line through data points plotted with ListPlot?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a set of data which I thread together...

```
xx = {16, 128, 256, 1024, 2048, 4096, 16384, 32768}
yy = {282991, 6182, 5521, 9072, 4874, 1043, 1168, 1225}
Thread[{xx, yy}]
```

Then I say... ListPlot[Thread[{xx, yy}]]... This gets me a set of dots but I need to connect them with a line. If I use ListLinePlot then I can get the line but there's no dots. I need both. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Show[ListPlot[Thread[{xx, yy}]], ListPlot[Thread[{xx, yy}], Joined->True]]

Comment: try `Joined->True,Mesh->All`

Answer (score 2):

```
ListLinePlot[Thread[{xx, yy}], PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```